# File Size wrong node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

When downloading small 25mb chunks from a big file, the chunks are acutally much larger then 25mb. Can someone please help.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const files = fs.readdirSync('../in/')
files.map(fileName => {
  const readable = fs.createReadStream('../in/'+fileName)
  let size = 0

  let temp_chunk;
  let count = 0 

  readable.on("data", (chunk) => {
    temp_chunk += chunk
    const byteSize = new Blob([chunk]).size;

    size += byteSize
    let amount = size / 1000000
    amount = amount.toString()
    amount = amount.substring(0, 5) + 'mb'

    console.log(amount)
    if (amount > 24.5) {
      console.log(fileName+' '+count+' downloaded')
      fs.writeFileSync('../out/'+fileName+count, temp_chunk)
      temp_chunk = ''
      size = 0
      count++
    }
  })
})
```

i tried reading the size of the file, from temp_chunk, this worked but made download significantly slower.

Comment: You are comparing a string (`"27.46mb"`) and a number. And you only enforce the minimum size, not the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WHATWG standard streams (which have been part of Node [since v17](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v17.x/api/fs.html#filehandlereadablewebstream)) to read and buffer bytes before emitting. Using this pattern will also increase portability of your code to other environments (e.g. browsers, Deno, Bun, etc.)

A `TransformStream` ([Node](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/webstreams.html#class-transformstream), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TransformStream)) which buffers up to a parameterized byte length before emitting might look like this:

`buffered_byte_stream.mjs`:

```js
import { TransformStream } from "node:stream/web";

export class BufferedByteStream extends TransformStream {
  #buf = [];
  constructor(byteLength) {
    super({
      flush: (controller) => {
        if (this.#buf.length >= byteLength) {
          controller.enqueue(Uint8Array.from(this.#buf.splice(0, byteLength)));
        }
        if (this.#buf.length > 0) {
          controller.enqueue(
            Uint8Array.from(this.#buf.splice(0, this.#buf.length)),
          );
        }
      },
      transform: (chunk, controller) => {
        this.#buf.push(...chunk);
        if (this.#buf.length >= byteLength) {
          controller.enqueue(Uint8Array.from(this.#buf.splice(0, byteLength)));
        }
      },
    });
  }
}
```

And then using it in your main application code might look like this:

`main.mjs`:

```js
import * as fs from "node:fs/promises";
import * as path from "node:path";
import { WritableStream } from "node:stream/web";

import { BufferedByteStream } from "./buffered_byte_stream.mjs";

function createWritableDestination(filePath) {
  let index = 0;
  return new WritableStream({
    async write(u8Arr) {
      const { base, dir } = path.parse(filePath);
      const fileName = `${base}.part${(index++).toString().padStart(3, "0")}`;
      console.log(`downloaded: ${fileName}`);
      await fs.writeFile(path.join(dir, fileName), u8Arr);
    },
  });
}

const inputDir = "../in";
const outputDir = "../out";
const byteLengthLimit = 25e6; // 25MB

for (const entry of await fs.readdir(inputDir, { withFileTypes: true })) {
  if (!entry.isFile()) continue; // Skip non-files
  const fileHandle = await fs.open(path.join(inputDir, entry.name));
  try {
    await fileHandle
      .readableWebStream({ type: "bytes" }) // ReadableStream<Uint8Array>
      .pipeThrough(new BufferedByteStream(byteLengthLimit))
      .pipeTo(createWritableDestination(path.join(outputDir, entry.name)));
  } finally {
    await fileHandle.close();
  }
}
```

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#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)

Answer (score -1):

Use a Buffer to concatenate chunks. Directly concatenating binary data with += on a string (like temp_chunk += chunk) is not appropriate for binary data and can lead to unexpected results.

## Solution

```
const fs = require('fs');
const files = fs.readdirSync('../in/');
files.forEach(fileName => {
  const readable = fs.createReadStream('../in/' + fileName);
  let size = 0;
  let temp_chunk = Buffer.alloc(0); // Initialize as an empty buffer
  let count = 0;

  readable.on("data", (chunk) => {
    temp_chunk = Buffer.concat([temp_chunk, chunk]);
    size += chunk.length; // Use chunk.length to get the size in bytes

    let amount = size / 1000000; // Convert to megabytes

    console.log(amount + 'mb');
    if (amount > 24.5) {
      console.log(fileName + ' ' + count + ' downloaded');
      fs.writeFileSync('../out/' + fileName + count, temp_chunk);
      temp_chunk = Buffer.alloc(0); // Reset to an empty buffer
      size = 0;
      count++;
    }
  });

  readable.on("end", () => {
    if (temp_chunk.length > 0) {
      // Write the remaining chunk if there is any
      console.log(fileName + ' ' + count + ' downloaded (last chunk)');
      fs.writeFileSync('../out/' + fileName + count, temp_chunk);
    }
  });
});
```